# Задать стиль у дива из JS

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

На странице  есть JS, в котором высчитаны некоторые переменные. В теле страницы есть определенные дивы, которым охота задать ширину и высоту именно с этими переменными. Может кто подсказать, как это сделать?

```
//Допустим этим:
<div class="my1">
    <div class="my2">
    </div>
</div>

//нужно добавить
class my1 -> width: 'var_my1w'.px
class my2 -> width: 'var_my2w'.px
class my1 -> height: 'var_my1h'.px
class my2 -> height: 'var_my2h'.px
```

id у элементов ест-но присутствует

Подскажите, как реализовать? А то сейчас всю страницу через JS вывожу ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID элементов или классы? в коде у вас классы. если используете jQuery то так:

```
$('.my1').css('width', var_my1w + 'px').css('height', var_my1h + 'px');
$('.my2').css('width', var_my2w + 'px').css('height', var_my2h + 'px');
```

Если без jQuery и у элементов классы, то немного сложнее так как придётся перечислить весь массив элементов, примерно так:

```
var f1 = document.getElementsByClassName('my1');
for (var i=0; i<f1.length; i++) {
    f1[i].style.width = var_my1w + 'px';
    f1[i].style.height = var_my1h + 'px';
}

var f2 = document.getElementsByClassName('my2');
for (var i=0; i<f1.length; i++) {
    f1[i].style.width = var_my2w + 'px';
    f1[i].style.height = var_my2h + 'px';
}
```

Если объектов много, можно "замутить" функцию:

```
resizeDiv('my1', 100, 100);

function resizeDiv(xclass, xwidth, xheight) {
    var f1 = document.getElementsByClassName(xclass);
      for (var i=0; i<f1.length; i++) {
        f1[i].style.width = xwidth + 'px';
        f1[i].style.height = xheight + 'px';
      }    
}
```

Если у элемент**А** всё таки ID, то так:

```
var f1 = document.getElementById('my1');
f1.style.width = var_my1w + 'px'; f1.style.height = var_my1h + 'px';
```

или jQuery:

```
$('#my1').css('width', var_my1w + 'px').css('height', var_my1h + 'px');
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/8v9FK/

Как видите код jQuery более компактный и читаемый, но если она не используется, подключать её только ради этой задач - ненужно. и помните, на странице не может быть двух элементов с одинаковым ID. Удачи Вам!

Comment: Код суперский! Причем весь. По поводу компактности - согласен, просто в силу требований моего 'Мьсье' нужно JS (под предлогом скорости). Хотя на будущее именно JQ адекватнее использовать

Comment: Подумал: можно забить в функцию если ресайзить много объектов: http://jsfiddle.net/dMxSA/1/